# Get 'var' from javascript to $ php

Tags: javascript, php, select

How can I get `val` value from javascript and add it in php?

Note: When I change selectbox -> alert showing for all values, it should show no thing when d == 1 but it show it for all.

```
<?php
    if ($rows['plus'] < $Stime OR $rows['plus'] == 0) {
        $saveal = mysql_query("UPDATE `".TB_PREFIX."users` SET plus = 0 WHERE id = \"".$userid."\"");
        echo "<b>غير مفعّل</b> ";
        $activ = array('يوم','يومان','3 أيام','4 أيام','5 أيام','6 أيام','7 أيام');
?> 
    <script language="javascript">
        function updateplus(){
            var d = document.getElementById("select_day").selectedindex;
            if (d == 0){
                var vla = 1;
            }else if (d == 1) {
                var val =2;
            }else{
                alert("please select value");
            }

        }
    </script>
    <select name="select_day" id="select_day" onchange="updateplus()">
  <?php
    foreach($activ as $key => $value):
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
    endforeach;
    //$saveal2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `".TB_PREFIX."users` SET plus = \"".$s."\" WHERE id = \"".$userid."\"");
    ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: No you can't pass the javascript variable directly to php variables. php is working on the server-side somewhere while javascript is working on your browser. to pass value from javascript either you sent it to php via get method or post.

Comment: So how can I get $(something) = (selectedkey) + 1 ?

Comment: What value are you trying to pass on select tag?

Comment: I want to set a value that selected from select box (text or number) fex: $d = $_POST['select_day']

Comment: value from updateplus function?

Comment: yes from updateplus or forget javascript and do it on php.

Comment: What about answers?